# How to open a network drive on MacOS?

Tags: terminal, finder, network, catalina

On Windows if I want to open the internal bugzilla file server I just used to `run` (Windows+R ) `//engweb.eng.company.com/bugs/files/` and it would open up the files on the Windows explorer.

How do I achieve something similar on Mac?

Things I have tried:

1. Cmd+k, Connect to file server but it just keeps waiting and then times out. I have no idea whether smb is the right protocol that should be used.
2. Use `open` from the terminal, again not sure about the protocol.

Note: New MacOS user

Answer (score 2):

Try to ping the website as an example
 `ping engweb.eng.company.com`, 
and get the IP of it.

Then from "Connect to Server", put the network path as `IP/bugs/files` , and try to connect it as `smb://IP/bugs/files` .

It could be an FTP network path so, worth to try `ftp://IP/bugs/files`, also you can try with `cifs://IP.bugs/files` if the above-mentioned option didn't work.